# Linguistic meaning of 'let' variable in programming

Tags: javascript, swift, ecmascript-6, linguistics

So, I'm a javascript programmer and the new version of [JavaScript (ES6)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) has a new keyword for declaring variables: `let`, next to the old one `var`.

I know the difference between these two, but I was asking myself: what does `let` stand for? `var` obviously is an abbreviation of *"**var**iable"*, but `let`? Is it an abbreviation as well? Where does it come from?

I googled this and to my amazement, I couldn't find an answer. I already knew [Swift](https://swift.org/) also has a `let` keyword (they use it for constants), but apparently some other programming languages use it as well.

Comment: hmm, I found this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194227/in-what-programming-language-did-let-first-appear, but it doesn't really give a clear answer

Comment: `let` stands for... drumroll please... [let](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/let). You could read `let x = 1;` as "let x be 1" if that helps.

Comment: it's an english verb; "_let_ this name be this value".

Comment: seriously, just that simple?

Comment: it stands for _lettuce_ because it _leaves_ itself behind...

Comment: @dandavis - hall of fame comment :-)

Comment: "Let" is commonly used in mathematics: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It comes from the English word 'let'.

> verb: "let", "letting".
>   1.
>   to allow or permit:

```
// Hey computer, can you please
let 
// this
night = 'wonderful'
```

[Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) has the keyword `let` and it's been around since 1958, though it may have come from [even earlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression#History).

Comment: I've always assumed programming languages inherited it from the language of mathematical proofs, which often say e.g. "Let *x* be an integer..."

Comment: @Jordan that's completely likely. You find `let` used more in functional programming languages which are built on algebraic types and category theory.

Comment: I always think of it more along the lines of "let the keyword `night` equal `'wonderful'`" but that's probably just me.

Comment: @Jordan I found an example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof#Proof_by_mathematical_induction